# How to force redirect http https on the entire domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I recently added a SSL certificate to my website and would like to redirect all pages to its secure "version".

Currently I have the following line in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase    /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I manually remove the https://www. from the url, it just shows the regular unprotected page.

How can I force all pages to https regardless of www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code in my main directory `(ex. https://www.example.com/.htaccess)` on my FTP server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [L]
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Not sure why mine didn't. I'll accept in 6 minutes.